# How do I get these divs stack on top of each other right in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I still don't really understand how to center divs. In this fiddle, you can see I have centered the divs but they're overlapping. I've set both to display inline-block thinking that would solve it, but that didn't do anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/fyu1sup0/1/

```
html, body {
  font-family:;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: Europa;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.container {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.top {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.top h1 {
  width:100%;
  font-size:50px;
  color:#2CCDAD;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.bottom h1 {
  font-size:40px;
  color:black;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a wrapper element. Then use `transform: translateY(-50%)` to adjust the position of the wrapper to the center of the page.

See https://jsfiddle.net/Labo59nx/

```css
html, body {
  font-family:;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: Europa;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -150px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.top {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 15;
  display:inline-block;
}
.top h1 {
  width:100%;
  font-size:50px;
  color:#2CCDAD;
}

.bottom {
  background-color:red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 15;
  display:inline-block;
}
.bottom h1 {
  font-size:40px;
  color:black;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
    
      <div class = "top">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>header</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class = "bottom">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>text</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `position: absolute`, you could wrap `top` and `bottom` in a new wrapper and use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Note that I've also added a `height` property to the `body` to make this work.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/fyu1sup0/2/)

```css
html,
body {
  font-family;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: Europa;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.top h1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #2CCDAD;
}

.bottom {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  /* for demo */
}

.bottom h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="top">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```